# Why aren't closure helper instances (DisplayClass) only created when actually needed?

Tags: c#, closures, heap-memory, allocation

I have a question regarding closures and heap allocation. Consider the following code:

```
//ORIGINAL CODE, VERSION 1
public class Program
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();
    
    public object Test(String x){
        
        if(x == "abort") return null;
        
        return _coll.GetOrAdd(x, (k)=> TestCallback());
    }
    
    public static object TestCallback() => null;
}
```

Within `Test` a `static` callback function is used. And, according to https://sharplab.io, this gets *lowered* to (abbr.):

```
//LOWERED CODE, VERSION 1
public class Program
{
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c(); // <== HELPER1 CREATION

        public static Func<object, object> <>9__1_0;

        internal object <Test>b__1_0(object k)
        {
            return TestCallback();
        }
    }

    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();

    public object Test(string x)
    {
        if (x == "abort")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _coll.GetOrAdd(x, <>c.<>9__1_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__1_0 = new Func<object, object>(<>c.<>9.<Test>b__1_0)));  // <== HELPER2 CREATION
    }

    public static object TestCallback() //==> STATIC METHOD
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, the compiler creates a few helper objects, but does this only **once** (the helpers are static).

Now, if I remove `static` from `TestCallback`...:

```
//ORIGINAL CODE, VERSION 1
public class Program
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();
    
    public object Test(String x){
        
        if(x == "abort") return null;
        
        return _coll.GetOrAdd(x, (k)=> TestCallback());
    }
    
    public object TestCallback() => null; //==> INSTANCE METHOD
}
```

...the lowered code changes to:

```
//LOWERED CODE, VERSION 2
public class Program
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();

    public object Test(string x)
    {
        if (x == "abort")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _coll.GetOrAdd(x, new Func<object, object>(<Test>b__1_0)); // <== HELPER1 CREATION
    }

    public object TestCallback()
    {
        return null;
    }

    private object <Test>b__1_0(object k)
    {
        return TestCallback();
    }
}
```

It now appears that a `new Func` is created on *every* call, if `x == "abort"` is not true (i.e. `_coll.GetOrAdd` is actually called).

Finally, if I change `Test` to include a `callback` parameter...:

```
//ORIGINAL CODE, VERSION 3
public class Program
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();
    
    public object Test(String x, Func<object> callback){
        
        if(x == "abort") return null;
        
        return _coll.GetOrAdd(x, (k)=> callback());
    }
}
```

...the lowered code changes to:

```
//LOWERED CODE, VERSION 3
public class Program
{
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass1_0
    {
        public Func<object> callback;

        internal object <Test>b__0(object k)
        {
            return callback();
        }
    }

    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();

    public object Test(string x, Func<object> callback)
    {
        <>c__DisplayClass1_0 <>c__DisplayClass1_ = new <>c__DisplayClass1_0(); // <== HELPER1 CREATION
        <>c__DisplayClass1_.callback = callback;
        if (x == "abort")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _coll.GetOrAdd(x, new Func<object, object>(<>c__DisplayClass1_.<Test>b__0)); // <== HELPER2 CREATION
    }
}
```

Here, it appears as if, a `new <>c__DisplayClass1_0` is created on *every* call, regardless of `x == "abort"`.

To summarize:

- Version1: create 2 helpers once.
- Version2: create 1 helper whenever `_cao..GetOrAdd` is actually called.
- Version3: create 2 helper on every call.

Is this correct? If the lowered code is correct (and is what the actual compiler uses), why is the creation of `new <>c__DisplayClass1_0` not done immediately before the relevant call?

Then unneccessary allocations would be prevented. Ultimately I'm wondering, if this is an actual improvement:

```
public IMetadata GetOrDefineMetadata(object key, Func<IMetadata> createCallback)
{
    if (_coll.TryGetValue(key, out var result)) return result; //THIS LINE WAS INSERTED AS AN IMPROVEMENT

    return _coll.GetOrAdd(key, (k) => createCallback()); // ==> WILL THIS STILL CAUSE ALLOCATIONS ON EVERY CALL?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an opportunity for a compiler optimization.

I moved the call to _coll.GetOrAdd to a static method. In the lowered code this moves the allocation further down.

```
public class Program
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();

    public object Test(String x, Func<object> callback){
        
        if(x == "abort") return null;
    
        return GetOrAdd(x, _coll, callback);
    }

    private static object GetOrAdd(string x, ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> dict,  Func<object> callback)
        {
        return dict.GetOrAdd(x, (_)=> callback());
    }
}
```

Lowered version:

```
public class Program
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass2_0
    {
        public Func<object> callback;

        internal object <GetOrAdd>b__0(object _)
        {
            return callback();
        }
    }

    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _coll = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();

    public object Test(string x, Func<object> callback)
    {
        if (x == "abort")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return GetOrAdd(x, _coll, callback);
    }

    private static object GetOrAdd(string x, ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> dict, Func<object> callback)
    {
        <>c__DisplayClass2_0 <>c__DisplayClass2_ = new <>c__DisplayClass2_0();
        <>c__DisplayClass2_.callback = callback;
        return dict.GetOrAdd(x, new Func<object, object>(<>c__DisplayClass2_.<GetOrAdd>b__0));
    }
}
```